# Как отправить неизвестный другой программе объект через ObjectOutputStream?

Tags: java, сокет, сериализация

ответьте пожалуйста, как можно отправить неизвестный получателю класс через `Socket`?

---

Есть код клиента (отправителя) и некий класс, в реальности гораздо более сложный:

```
Socket socket_in = new Socket(...);
ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(socket_in.getOutputStream());
out.writeObject(new UNClass(10));
out.flush();

private static class UNClass implements Serializable {
    private static final long SerialVersionUID = 1234L;
    public final int val;
    public UNClass(int val) {
        this.val = val;
    }
}
```

Есть код сервера (получателя):

```
ServerSocket s = new ServerSocket(...);
Socket socket_in = s.accept();

ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(socket_in.getInputStream());

Object unclass = in.readObject(); //Получение UNClass
... //Привести Object к UNClass
int rec_val = unclass.val;
```

---

Мне нужно каким либо образом получить полностью функционирующий класс `UNClass`, если во второй программе он не объявлен. Как это лучше сделать?
Создать такой-же класс во второй программе не вариант.

Comment: Можно просто передать и получить единичный `int`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не зная предварительно ничего о классе будет трудно сделать его полностью функционирующим, хотя рефлексия позволяет сделать нечто подобное.

Передайте сам объект и его класс:

```
out.writeObject(UNClass.class); // передаем класс
out.writeObject(new UNClass(10)); // передаем объект
```

Во второй программе получите оба объекта

```
Class unclassClass = (Class) in.readObject();
Object unclass =  unclassClass.cast(in.readObject());
```

Получите поля и методы вашего нового класса

```
java.lang.reflect.Field[] fields = unclassClass.getDeclaredFields();
java.lang.reflect.Method[] methods = unclassClass.getMethods();
```

Используйте их

```
methods[0].invoke(unclass); // вызвать один из методов объекта
fields[0].get(unclass); // получить значение одного из полей объекта
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, получается что так просто не получится передать класс не известный другой программе.

Answer (score 1):

Если вы по каким то причинам не хотите передавать объект целиком, а хотите передать только часть его данных - вы можете создать промежуточный класс для их передачи, так называемый [DTO](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/DTO). 
Вложите в его экземпляр необходимые данные и получите их на другой стороне.
Без необходимости объявлять исходный класс со всеми данными и поведением целиком.

Comment: Я не очень хорошо выразился в вопросе, мне нужно получить объект гораздо большей сложности, здесь же я его сильно упростил буквально до одного поля int.